# Who played Sebastian in Suddenly Last Summer?

Tags: casting, suddenly-last-summer

Sebastian Venable is an important character in the film adaptation of Suddenly Last Summer, yet his face is never shown nor is the actor who portrayed him listed in the film credits.

Is there anyway of learning who played this part?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[**Julian Ugarte**](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0880068/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t18)

> Julián Ugarte was born on June 6, 1929 in Sestao, Vizcaya, País Vasco, Spain as Julián Ugarte Landa. He was an actor, known for The Pride and the Passion (1957), Los libros (1974) and All the Colors of the Dark (1972). He was married to Didi Sherman. He died on December 27, 1987 in Bilbao, Vizcaya.

[image]